# Multiple instructions for np.where python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to do something like :

```
if condition: 
    instruction 1 
    instruction 2
    ...
    instruction N
```

Do I have to repeat the np.where statement multiple times ?

```
my_df["1"] = np.where(condition, instruction1, other)
my_df["2"] = np.where(condition, instruction2, other)
...
my_df["N"] = np.where(condition, instructionN, other)
```

Comment: Please don't get into abstract programming. Keep it practical. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details, maybe something like that:

```
instructions = [instruction1, instruction2, ..., instructionN]

for i in range(len(instructions)):
    my_df[str(i+1)] = np.where(condition, instructions[i], other)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My concern is time processing as I have huge dataframes. You solution is a cleaner way of writing. But I'm looking for a solution with only one np.where, if it can be done.